# Javascript - prevent captcha alert OK button from triggering submit on mailchimp form

Tags: javascript, forms, mailchimp

I am trying to add my own simple number captcha to my mailchimp form. I have a function that checks the captcha which works if the form fields are not filled out.

If the fields are entered correctly and you click submit, the captcha popup alert will trigger, as it should, but once you click OK, the form submits, without you having to enter the correct numbers.

How can I prevent the OK alert button from triggering the submit button?

Here is the captcha code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(form) {      
     if(!form.captcha.value.match(/^\d{5}$/)) {
         alert('Please enter the CAPTCHA digits in the box provided'); 
         form.captcha.focus(); 
         return false;
       }
}
</script>
```

The mailchimp validation is in this format at the bottom of the page. I tried unsuccessfully to add it to the checkForm function but it won't work because it needs to get the validation from the src link which doesn't work in a function.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='LNAME';ftypes[2]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

Is it possible to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you also alter the HTML code?

You should change the button HTML property to `type=button` instead of `type=submit`, this will prevent automatic form submission on clicking.

Comment: Interesting.  I had it set to `type='image'` to use a submit button image.  If I change it to `type='button'` it disables the captcha box, `type='submit'` has the same affect as 'image' - OK activates the button.